# robust numerical calculation with large (almost) offsetting terms

Tags: numerics, stability

I am attempting to evaluate an expression that defines a probability of a particular event. With 3 different events, I can (under some statistical assumptions) characterize the probability of event 1 (for example) occurring as

$$\frac{e^{v_1+2 v_2} (v_2-v_1)}{\left(e^{v_2}-e^{v_1}\right)^2 \left(e^{v_2}-e^{v_3}\right)}+\frac{e^{v_1+2 v_3} (v_3-v_1)}{\left(e^{v_3}-e^{v_1}\right)^2 \left(e^{v_3}-e^{v_2}\right)}+\frac{e^{2 v_1}}{\left(e^{v_1}-e^{v_2}\right) \left(e^{v_1}-e^{v_3}\right)},$$

where $(v_1, v_2, v_3)$ are arbitrary real numbers that are associated with the different events. (I have general expressions for an arbitrary number of events, but I believe this case is sufficient to understand the problem.)

The practical numerical issue I have been struggling with is that the expression is not numerically robust when two or more elements in $(v_1, v_2, v_3)$ are numerically *similar* in value, as the denominator in the expression involves pairwise differences. In the case that they are *identical* I can calculate limits. However, when they similar the associated numerical error could result in an evaluation that is outside of the unit interval as at least two or more of the fraction terms in the expression will become very large in absolute terms (and theoretically almost offsetting).

Any help in how I should approach this would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried reformulating $e^{v_i} - e^{v_j} = e^{v_j} ( e^{v_i-v_j} - 1)$? In this case, you can use `expm1`, which is much more precise in the neighborhood of 0.

Comment: Thanks @cos_theta. I was not using this formulation with `expm1`. It helps a little, but it is still generally not very robust. This is particularly true when I have more than 3 events. (In this case, the formula would involves terms that have involve the product of more pairwise exponential differences)

Comment: Try herbie: https://herbie.uwplse.org/ It automatically finds (more) numerically stable formulations of expressions.